# Java button and listener not working in sync

Tags: java, swing

*Trying to add a button to an already made program in JAVA. It converts temperature from Fahrenheit to celsius. My button won't show up. I'm missing something. The idea is that you will be able to both press enter or the button to have a result. There's the main part of the program:*

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Fahrenheit
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Fahrenheit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FahrenheitPanel panel = new FahrenheitPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

***Then in a separate file:***

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FahrenheitPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
    private JButton push;
    private JTextField fahrenheit;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor: Sets up the main GUI components.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public FahrenheitPanel()
    {
        inputLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Fahrenheit temperature:");
        outputLabel = new JLabel ("Temperature in Celsius: ");
        resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");
        fahrenheit = new JTextField (5);
        fahrenheit.addActionListener (new TempListener());
        add (inputLabel);
        add (fahrenheit);
        add (outputLabel);
        add (resultLabel);

        //Here's some button code
        push = new JButton ("Push!!!");
        push.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        add (push);

        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 75));
        setBackground (Color.red);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        private class TempListener implements ActionListener
        {
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            // Performs the conversion when the enter key is pressed in
            // the text field.
            //--------------------------------------------------------------

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
            {
                int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;
                String text = fahrenheit.getText();
                fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
                celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;
                resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button won't show up as the `ActionListener` code doesn't compile as

- `ButtonListener` requires a `actionPerformed` method
- `TempListener` is an inner class of `ButtonListener` but is referenced as an outer class

The code can be simplified by using anonymous `ActionListeners` instead, for example

```
push.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ...
    }
});
```

Comment: So you think it should be :

`private class TempListener implements ActionListener`

Then 

`private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener`

Then
`public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)`

It's still not working. It tells me that "It cannot find symbol".

Comment: That error doesnt indicate what's wrong. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see the updated code

Comment: I got it to run! The code was convoluted I realized. I didn't need both listeners. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For what did you need `ButtonListener` and `TempListener`??

```
//Here's some button code
    push = new JButton ("Push!!!");
    add (push);

    push.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;
            String text = fahrenheit.getText();
            fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
            celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;
            resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
        }
    });
```

and for `fahrenheit`:

```
    ...
    add (fahrenheit);
    fahrenheit.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;
            String text = fahrenheit.getText();
            fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
            celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;
            resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
        }
    });
    ...
```